# Books for an introduction into higher level electronics

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, books

I’m looking for a book that will introduce me to higher level mathematics in electrical networks. Specifically calculus/multivariate calculus/vector calculus/Fourier transform. I’ve read many books on circuits but all fail to define the fundamental mathematics involved in the concepts they attempt to explain. I wish to understand the concepts at a (mathematical level) fundamental level.

Comment: What books does your course suggest?

Comment: I’m not in a course — I’m in high school but I have a heavy amount of math classes (I’m in several college math course) and I’ve been reading electronic books for 4 years now

Comment: Go here: [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) and start, say, with his "Essence of linear algebra" sections. Pretty much everything he creates is worth listening to.

Answer (score 1):

From what you’ve described I would recommend *Engineering Mathematics* by K. A. Stroud. The follow up book to this, *Advanced Engineering Mathematics* then gets into Fourier analysis and more.

Comment: Very good - still have mine - both of them...

Answer (score 1):

Read the book "Oliver Heaviside: Sage in Solitude" by Paul Nahin, IEEE press.

You'll enjoy the history, the struggles, the various opposing (egotistic) forces, the uncovering of truth in the models used, the principles behind the
vector calculus, and the operational mathematics invented by Heaviside.

Plan on rereading it every couple years, as your understanding of the field
allows your intellectual evolution to cause appreciation of more aspects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced you'll find a book with the rigour you seek and all the derivation and intuition to go with it.  But if you're up for the challenge, that can be a blessing in disguise.  I like the idea of a kind of "learning pyramid".  Where you find yourself a good book (they typically concentrate on a narrow subject area) with plenty of rigour, but which can be challenging to read.  Then use that book to drive investigations across a number of good reference sources (many mentioned in other answers and comments).

Take plenty of notes.  I often set up a notepad where I put all my own intuition and derivations so I can flip back at a later stage.  This will be a big effort, but the reward is priceless.  In the end, you will remember your efforts much better than had you been spoonfed the answers.

At the moment, I'm reading "Communication Circuits Analysis & Design" by Clarke & Hess, an all-time RF favourite.  This is my "driving book", full of insight and rigour, but quite challenging.  Very often, I need to refer to other sources (including Stroud!, the internet, this site, etc) and I take my notes.  Don't cheat (yourself), there's a nugget in every paragraph if you take the time to see it.